# Express static file is not updating

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm running a local server with express. The server is able to display some local files from my computer. Amongst them there is a file called "lastResult.txt" which gets updated every time I run a bash script.

For some reason, when I run the server and try to display the file, it shows a version from a week ago. This file file has been updated locally more recently than a week ago. This persists even after restarting the server or even on different browsers.

I am using the serve-index module to display directories.

Comment: If the file does not change when you restart the server, then either the browser is caching the file itself or you must not be displaying and updating the same file.  There is unlikely to be server-side caching that would survive a server restart.  You can look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger to see if the browser is loading that file from its own cache or if it is getting it from the server.  It's likely either browser caching or you aren't updating and displaying the same file on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't say how do you serve the static files - with express.static or with some custom handlers. The express.static doesn't cache the files but your custom handlers might. In any case, those files can be cached on the client depending on the value of ETag and Max-Age but even then they should not persist after accessing with another browser.

From what you're describing it seems that you are not updating the correct files, or in the correct directory. Of course it's impossible to be sure since you didn't include even a single line of your code so one can only speculate but it seems to be the case.

Comment: Yup this did the trick. It was retrieving the file from a custom location, but I didn't catch it since every other file in the directory was retrieved properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered.
I'm adding to it in case someone needs an example of a problem like this, (that is non-obvious).

Had a similar problem while using EJS and express.

- I was importing a header.
- The header loaded the CSS.
- There was a CSS file named base.css in two different folders (same CSS file name two different folders *projectroot/pages/base.css* && *projectroot/views/base.css* )
- The folder the header.ejs file was in was *projectroot/views/* (this is the base.css I wanted)
- From a path perspective to intentionally load the other css file should have required: `../pages/base.css`
- To be completely explicit I should have references the CSS file in the local directory like this: `./base.css` but instead I referenced it like `base.css`
- Surprisingly ... the CSS file that was being loaded was the one in the *projectroot/pages/* directory not the *projectroot/views/* directory
- Changing the reference to `./base.css` fixed the problem